# How do I map all routes in my MVC application to a static file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently writing a single page application and would like to map all incoming requests (except /api/{controller}) to my web application to a static file (index.html) in root. The routes to /api need to be accessible for WebApi calls from the front end. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the IIS 7 [`url rewrite module`](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing). This module is part of the IIS Express webserver, so you don't need anything special to enable it. And on your production IIS 7 server you might need to install and enable [`the extension`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Just add the following rule to your `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to index.html">
          <match url="^(?:(?!api\/))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Also since you are not using ASP.NET MVC you could get rid of the `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` file because you don't have any MVC controllers. Just keep the `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` where you will have a route for the `~/api` endpoint mapped to your Web API controllers:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, the redirect works. Is there any way to use a .cshtml file as target? Right now I'm using a simple html but in the long run I'd like to use a razor file but when changing the extension to cshtml I get an error 'The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. '

Comment: You can use `.cshtml` but you should not use ASP.NET MVC template which places .cshtml files in the ~/Views folder along with a ~/Views/web.config which forbids direct access to those templates (which is normal because in ASP.NET MVC you  never access a .cshtml directly, the request always goes through a controller). But since you want to have some dynamic nature, you probably want to serve this view through a controller, so why not follow the standard route anyways?

Comment: How can I construct this catch all route for directing requests to my Index action?

Comment: This seems to work for me:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default",               action="Index" }
            );